# Is there a way to know if widgets are shown on lock screen in iOS 10 using swift

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8, ios10-today-widget

In iOS10, today widgets can be shown on lock screen. Is there a way to know whether it has been called on lock screen or not programatically using swift?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: no. One way is to access keychain, if you are able to do, its not locked. But, its not that efficient.